# can't create scratch org (fatal ended with exit code 0 no error description)

Tags: lightning-experience, salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, scratch-org, vs-code

I gather that this question has been asked before but so far I haven't found anyone with the same error (or lack thereof) since the VS code status says

> SFDX: Create a Default Scratch Org... successfully ran

But the output reads

> Starting SFDX: Create a Default Scratch Org...
>
> 16:18:46.788 sfdx force:org:create -f config\project-scratch-def.json
> --setalias trailhead --durationdays 7 --setdefaultusername --json --loglevel fatal
>
> 16:19:14.800 sfdx force:org:create -f config\project-scratch-def.json --setalias trailhead --durationdays 7
> --setdefaultusername --json --loglevel fatal ended with exit code 0

I was following along [this Create a Lightning Web Component module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/set-up-your-lightning-web-components-developer-tools/create-a-lightning-web-component?trail_id=build-lightning-web-components) and everything was going fine until step 3, "create a scratch org." I did of course login (*sfdx force:auth:web:login -d -a DevHub* just in case) and frankly that step just says "select SFDX: Create a Default Scratch Org and press Enter 3 times" so it shouldn't be this complicated... I just updated to the newest CLI version too. What can I do about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sfdx force:org:create -f config/project-scratch-def.json --setalias <alias> --durationdays 7 
    --setdefaultusername --json --loglevel fatal
```

is the expected command for Salesforce DX to run. The word `fatal` is the argument of the option `--loglevel`, not an indication of an error; that logging level suppresses output messages other than a fatal failure.

Exit code 0 connotes a successful command run.

Barring some other indication of a failure, your scratch org request succeeded.

Comment: Thank you, I was thrown off by the instructions that said it would show a "success" message (that never appeared) but I just managed to push to the scratch org! Thanks again, I'm really new to CLIs in general

Comment: Had the same problem — thanks!